# Contar las veces que se repite un registro con varios criterios

Tags: excel

Estoy trabajando sobre un libro Excel, en el cual requiero contar ciertos registros que se repiten en una columna, pero que cumpla con varios criterios.

Criterios:
Columna "E", donde la celda diga "Produccion" hasta donde la celda diga "Produccion Final".
Siempre y cuando en ese rango el código de producto en la columna "G" sea el mismo 
Entonces, contar las veces que se repite en ese rango el valor "Ejemplo Ajuste" e ir sumando el valor de la columna D.

Lo intente con un CountIf, pero solo he podido contar todas las veces que se repite ese valor, sin los criterios mencionados.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea que pueda ayudarme a resolver el problema, se lo agradeceria.

Los datos son variables, regularmente mas de 50.000 registros. 
Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De antemano Muchas Gracias!!!
Edito subi un ejemplo con la formula Contar.Si.Conjunto, pero no es lo que busco.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16uF1qC9YpJyTzUzjqWf4KoaEqRAUZh_x?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hola. Hablas de contar valores entre "Producción" y "Producción Final" para un mismo código de Producción pero en el C6607 no hay un campo "Producción Final" luego no entraría dentro de lo que buscas. Con el C8899 no habría problema pero ya te digo que en tu primer ejemplo no me cuadran los datos.

De todas formas con una tabla dinámica puedes agrupar por Código y contar los "Ejemplo Ajuste" que aparecen.

Comment: @dogwall
Perdon es correcto en el C6607 tuve un error al transcribir los registros.
Con una tabla dinamica puedo agrupar por Código y contar los "Ejemplo Ajuste" pero no siempre cumplirian con los criterios mencionados "Produccion" y "Produccion Final" pueden existir muchos registros "Producción" en un rango variable de registros. ademas de que hablo que normalmente son mas de 50.000 registros los que hay que revisar.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer perfectamente con un CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO. Y el total time con un SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debido a que quieres contar en un rango en concreto, que además es dinámico, tienes que usar INDIRECTO para recrear el rango, COINCIDIR para localizar la primera fila, y ahí ya contar:

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(INDIRECTO("D"&COINCIDIR("Produccion";D:D;0)&":D99999");"Ejemplo Ajuste";INDIRECTO("F"&COINCIDIR("Produccion";D:D;0)&":F99999");I3)
```

Funciona así:

1. `COINCIDIR("Produccion";D:D;0)` Nos devuelve el nº de fila de la palabra `Producción` (la primera coincidencia). En este caso es 20
2. El 20 obtenido anteriormente lo concatenamos con las columnas D y F para crear rangos en plan `D20:D99999` y `F20:F99999`. Estos rangos los referenciamos con INDIRECTO, una función muy útil
3. Una vez que tenemos `D20:D99999` y `F20:F99999` podemos usar un CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO normal y corriente, aplicando los criterios definidos.

Esto obtiene el resultado que deseas:
[image]

Comment: He agregado un ejemplo a mi Drive, probe la formula recomendada pero no es lo que espero como resultado.
Espero lo puedan visualizar.

Comment: ¿Por qué las filas 54 y 55 no cuentan para `C8899`?

Comment: 54 y 55 si cuentan, subi el archivo incorrecto de nuevo una disculpa.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16uF1qC9YpJyTzUzjqWf4KoaEqRAUZh_x?usp=sharing

Comment: @JoseDanielSolis Mira la respuesta actualizada. Esa fórmula hace exactamente lo que pides. Devuelve 2 y 5

Comment: Muchas gracias, va muy bien voy a seguir profundizando en esas formulas dado que no habia hecho uso de ellas.